# Set environment variable "FLUTTER_GIT_URL" to unknown source to dismiss this error

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

When I type "doctor -v" into the terminal in Flutter, I get the following result. What should I do ?
! Upstream repository unknown source is not a standard remote.
Set environment variable "FLUTTER_GIT_URL" to unknown source to dismiss this error.

I wanted to run the project on iOS and I got an error like this: /Users/budak/Desktop/AnatoliaSystem/iko/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m:12:9 Module 'path_provider_foundation' not found

Then, when I ran the doctor -v command, the problem I shared appeared.[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4Fae.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGCQK.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I don't know how to fix my problems with the flutter doctor command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**step 1**

```
which flutter # **output your flutter sdk  path , cd your flutter directory**
```

**step 2**

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git &&  git checkout 3.16.9 #replace 3.16.9 your projce flutter version
```

**step 3**

```
export FLUTTER_GIT_URL=https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git && flutter doctor  -v # print check your flutter doctor info
```

step 4

```
flutter channel #fixed Upstream repository unknown source is not the same as FLUTTER_GIT_URL
```

step 5

```
flutter channel stable # set your flutter channel
```